# Prevent copy/use of third party licensed libraries when distributing a .NET application

Tags: .net, security, distribution

I'm developing a .NET application that relies on third party libraries.
These libraries were paid and licensed to my company and I want to avoid anyone that uses the application to just copy the libraries and use them for themselves.

I was interested to know what is the general way to deal with this issue but, if it matters, I'm developing a Silverlight application using Telerik controls.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues, not programming.

Comment: @Mogsdad can you recommend the right place to ask this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about this. If someone would do that, it would be a simple copyright infringement just like downloading them from some dubious web site.
Furthermore, your application contains the license and the controls most likely won't run without it.